# How to split text using certain delimitation

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, regex, string

I have the current scenario

```
string b = "{Lorem ipsum dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
Ut enim adminim veniam, quis {nostrud exercitation};
```

I want to split the string b this way:

```
   string[] splittedString = new string[] {
  "{Lorem ipsum dolor}",
  "sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis", 
  "{nostrud exercitation}" };
```

how do I achieve this using regex?

Comment: You are going to split on the Comma

Comment: the text is dynamic it could come without commas the delimitation would be `{any value inside}`

Comment: Picking out the `{text goes here}` parts is easy (just use groups).  Picking out the parts with no delimiters will be harder.  You may want to pick out the groups and then make a second pass and pickup the parts you left behind

Comment: You could use regex.split

Comment: `b.split(new [] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` will get you those parts without any curley braces.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/647232/Regex-Split-select-in-square-brackets change the square brackets to { and }

Comment: @RufusL do you known the equivalent using Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution that uses Regex.  It also handles the case where there's text before the first `{` and/or after the last `]`.

First the Regex and the string to parse:

```
//Regex: get things that start with a {, followed by one or more non-} characters, followed by a } 
private const string Pattern = @"(\{[^\}]+\})";
private const string TheText = "{Lorem ipsum dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Ut enim adminim veniam, quis {nostrud exercitation}";
```

Then some code:

```
 var regex = new Regex(Pattern);
 var matches = regex.Matches(TheText);
 var results = new List<string>();
 var currentIndex = 0;
 foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
 {
     var lastIndex = currentIndex;
     //pickup any undelimited text at the beginning or between delimited groups
     if (match.Index != currentIndex)
     {
         var unDelimited = TheText.Substring(currentIndex, match.Index - lastIndex);
         results.Add(unDelimited);
         currentIndex += unDelimited.Length;
     }
     results.Add(match.Groups[0].ToString());
     currentIndex += match.Length;
 }

 //finally pickup any undelimited text at the end
 if (TheText.Length > currentIndex)
 {
     results.Add(TheText.Substring(currentIndex));
 }
```

It relies on the Regex to find each of the `{some text here}` matches.  Then it walks through those matches, creating a list from either the match directly, or from substrings of the original string (using the position information of the matches).

I also tested it with a string like:

```
private const string TheText = "before {first} middle {second} after";
```

Finally, my code keeps any leading or trailing spaces in the undelimited text.  You can get rid of those with `string.Trim`